# $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le \frac{\ln(n+1)}{n^2}$ Prove that $a_n$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that for all $n$:

$$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le \frac{\ln(n+1)}{n^2}$$

Prove that $a_n$ is a convergent sequence. I was thinking of using Cauchy but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Please any help.

Comment: Why not? isn't the sequence Cauchy?

Comment: How can you show that?

Comment: For $n\gg 0$, $\ln(n+1)<\sqrt n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you know that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln (n+1)}{n^2}$ is convergent, the comparison test tells you that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{n+1} - a_n|$ is convergent, and the absolute convergence test tells you that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n+1} - a_n)$ is convergent. Write
$$
a_k = a_1 + \sum_{n=1}^{k-1}(a_{n+1} - a_n)$$
to conclude via the usual limit law that $\{a_k\}$ converges and
$$
a_k \to a_1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n+1} - a_n), \quad k \to \infty.$$

Comment: I'm actually confused. This series $\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}(a_{n+1} - a_n)$ is telescopic, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it is, and telescopes to $a_k - a_1$. That is the point of the argument.

Comment: Oh I see it now. How do you prove convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln (n+1)}{n^2}$?

Comment: $\ln(n+1)/\sqrt{n}\to 0$ and $\sum 1/n^{\frac 32}$ is convergent.

Comment: @zwim Are you using the limit comparison test?

Comment: Yes, saying $\ln(n+1)/\sqrt{n}$ converges to $0$ means also that it is $\le 1$ for $n\gg 1$. So the initial series is $\le \sum 1/n^{\frac 32}\to C$. Since the initial series has positive terms it is increasing and bounded by $C$ so it is convergent. This is essentially how the limit comparison test works.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Cauchy  sequence since for every $p\ge 1$

$$\begin{align}|a_{n+p}-a_n| &\le \sum_{j=1}^{p}|a_{n+j}-a_{n+j-1}| \le\sum_{j=1}^{p} \frac{\ln(n+j)}{(n+j-1)^2}\\ &\le \sum_{j=1}^{p} \frac{\ln(n+j)}{n^2}  =\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\ln(1+\frac{j}{n}) \\&\le C\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\to 0\end{align} $$

Indeed $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\ln(1+\frac{j}{n})$ is a bounded sequence since  by Riemann sum, we have $$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\ln(1+\frac{j}{n}) \le\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{\max(p,n)}\ln(1+\frac{j}{n}) \to\int_0^1\ln(1+x)dx$$

Comment: Care to explain the 3rd step?

Comment: By riemann sume of $\ln(1+x)$

Comment: @MisterBister see the edit

Answer (score 0):

Since $\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)\ge-\frac1{n+1}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\log(n+1)}{n-1}-\frac{\log(n+2)}n
&=\frac{\log(n+1)+n\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)}{n(n-1)}\\
&\ge\frac{\log(n+1)}{n^2}-\frac1{(n+1)(n-1)}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{\log(n+1)}{n^2}\\
&=\log(2)+\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{\log(n+1)}{n^2}\\
&\le\log(2)+\sum_{n=2}^m\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{n-1}-\frac{\log(n+2)}n\right)+\sum_{n=2}^m\frac1{(n+1)(n-1)}\\
&=\log(2)+\log(3)-\frac{\log(m+2)}m+\frac12\sum_{n=2}^m\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n+1}\right)\\
&=\log(2)+\log(3)-\frac{\log(m+2)}m+\frac12\left(1+\frac12-\frac1m-\frac1{m+1}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
which is bounded above by $\log(6)+\frac34$.

Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\frac{\log(n+1)}{n^2}$ is an increasing sequence bouned above, it converges.

Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty|a_{n+1}-a_n|$ converges, the sequence is Cauchy and therefore converges.